# Ember transition retry with query params

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

So I have application authentication logic in my ember app.  When the user hits a route that they need to be authenticated to enter, they are transitioned to the Login route and the original route they wanted to hit is saved.  When they login, I check to see if there was an original route to transition back to and send them back to that at that point.

This works fine, except when there are query params in the original route.  The transition should send them to '#/OldRoute/3' (for example), but instead it sends them to '#/OldRoute/undefined'

How can I retry a transition while maintaining the query params?

Comment: At the point where you are saving the original route, can't you save the model used for that route too? so that when time comes to redirect them to the original route after authentication you do so with the model needed.

Comment: The user is hitting the site from a url like 'site.com/#/Ticket/X' (where X is the ticket's ID).  After they log in it should take them to that ticket.  At the time that I am saving the transition there will not be a model to save (unless the query params are represented in the model property of my controller?).  I can't fetch the ticket from the server until after they authenticate, so I need to use the query param specifically later on to grab the ticket

Comment: not a bad idea, and it was right under my nose haha...post as an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: Yeah happens sometimes, glad to be a help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need proper model to redirect to nested route, so lets see, may be you can save the route and the parameter(X) too. Once you have authenticated the user, you might want to fetch the model(ticket model with id X) from the store based on the route name (original route) and then only do transition with the fetched model passed as parameter to transitionToRoute function.